# Retrieving only one row associated with an attribute from a data frame

Tags: apache-spark, hive

It would be helpful if you provide the solution for this.

I need a single row for unique col1 values. It need not be necessarily the first row for a particular col1 value

I have a table 'sample' in hive..

sample :

```
col1 col2 col3

1     a    b
1     c    d
1     e    f
2     g    h
2     i    j
3     k    l
```

I would like to obtain a table like this

sample1 :

```
col1 col2 col3

1      a    b
2      g    h
3      k    l
```

How to achieve this in spark using python ?

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am new to SQL also

Comment: We were all new at a certain point, we learned from reading documentations and text books. So being new is not an excuse to try !

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I didn't mention what all I have tried because it might be silly. I tried with group by(), distinct() etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using scala you can do

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, String,String)] = ...
rdd.groupBy( _._1 ).map( _._2.head )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first row for each col1 group:

```
select col1, first(col2), first(col3)
from sample
group by col1
```